# variable in regular expression not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to use variable in expression for auto increment id on add more. but when I add variable in expression it won't work and when I statically enter string "_1" in expression it work
 Here is code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var row_number_current  = 1;
    var row_number_increment = Number(row_number_current);
    row_number_increment += 1;

    var addMore = '<div id="data_box_1"><label for="chart-pie-text_1">Chart Text</label></div>';

    var row1 = addMore.replace("/_"+row_number_current+"/g", '_'+row_number_increment);
    var row2 = addMore.replace(/_1/g, '_'+row_number_increment);

    alert(row1);
    alert(row2);
});
```

result of row1 is

```
<div id="data_box_1"><label for="chart-pie-text_1">Chart Text</label></div>
```

and row2 result is

```
<div id="data_box_2"><label for="chart-pie-text_2">Chart Text</label></div>
```

Comment: Please up vote to my question I am no longer allowed to ask question due to down vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"/_"+row_number_current+"/g"` is a string, not a regex. You need to construct a regex using this string, then pass *that* as the `pattern` argument in replace:

```
var regex1 = new RegeExp("_"+row_number_current,"g");
var row1 = addMore.replace(regex1, '_'+row_number_increment);
```

In your particular case, however, you don't really need a regex. Just use a string:

```
var row1 = addMore.replace(row_number_current, row_number_increment, "g");
```

Comment: `var row1 = addMore.replace(row_number_current, row_number_increment);` it only replace first _1 not all

Comment: @DarkWish Yes, I've added the `g` flag

Comment: Please up vote to my question I am no longer allowed to ask question due to down vote

Answer (score 1):

In order to use variables in regular expressions, you have to create new [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) object and pass your expression as the first string argument:

```
var regex = new RegExp("_" + row_number_current, "g");
row1 = addMore.replace(regex, "_" + row_number_increment);
```

Comment: Please up vote to my question I am no longer allowed to ask question due to down vote